# importando um arquivo contendo uma função que escrevi: não enxerga variável global

Tags: python, python-3.x

arquivo ConstroiMatriz.py:

```
"""
Escreva uma função que recebe um inteiro m e outro n e com isso
constrói uma matriz mxn
"""
matrix = []

def main():
    m = int(input("Digite o número de linhas da matriz: "))
    n = int(input("Digite o número de colunas da matriz: "))


    def matriz(m,n):

        for i in range(1,m+1):
            linha = []
            for j in range(1,n+1):

                x= int(input("Digite o valor ({},{}): ".format(i,j)))
                linha.append(x)

            global matrix    
            matrix.append(linha)

        return matrix


    print(matriz(m,n))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Arquivo TrocaElementosMatriz.py:

```
"""
Escreva uma função que troca um elemento por outro numa matriz
"""

#from ConstroiMatriz import matriz ##ConstroiMatriz.py que eu fiz
import ConstroiMatriz


def troca():

    pos1 = int(input("Digite a linha do elemento a ser trocado: "))
    pos2 = int(input("Digite a coluna do elemento a ser trocado: "))
    pos3 =int(input("Digite a linha do elemento a ser trocado: "))
    pos4 = int(input("Digite a coluna do elemento a ser trocado: "))

    global matrix

    matrix[pos1][pos2], matrix[pos3][pos4] = matrix[pos3][pos4],matrix[pos1][pos2]



matriz(1,1)    
troca()
```

Objetivo: usar a função matriz(m,n) definida em ConstroiMatriz.py no programa TrocaElementosMatriz.py e, assim, trocar 2 elementos da matriz criada em ConstroiMatriz.

Ao executar o arquivo TrocaElementosMatriz.py, recebo o erro :

```
matriz(1,1)
NameError: name 'matriz' is not defined
```

Alguma sugestão?

Answer (score 2):

A função `def matriz(m, n)` está declarada dentro da função `main()`, logo você não pode acessar `def matriz(m, n)` de nenhum outro lugar a não ser dentro de `main()`.

Pra resolver é só tirar `def matriz(m, n)` de dentro da `main()`.

```
def matriz(m,n):
    for i in range(1,m+1):
        linha = []
        for j in range(1,n+1):

            x= int(input("Digite o valor ({},{}): ".format(i,j)))
            linha.append(x)

        global matrix    
        matrix.append(linha)

    return matrix

def main():

    m = int(input("Digite o número de linhas da matriz: "))
    n = int(input("Digite o número de colunas da matriz: "))

    print(matriz(m,n))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: main não era para conter o meu programa inteiro? Não entendi bem para que serve main!

Comment: E onde coloco  matrix = [] ?

Comment: agora, ao rodar o ConstroiMatriz o erro é -> NameError: name 'm' is not defined

Comment: Então, o problema que você ta tendo é de escopo. Não é bem "importar" o programa todo.

Comment: realmente não sei! Estou tentando aprender esses conceitos!